# mysql query: one-to-many relationship records

Tags: php, mysql, join, innodb

i have a table (1) with the ff structure:

```
 this_table's_id | title | fk_1 | fk_2 | ...
```

and another table (2) with this structure:

```
id | fk_to_this_table's_id | ...
```

the second table contains multiple records that point to a particular entry in table 1. im learning mysql, so im asking is it possible to output the results of table 1 while also outputting everything what's inside table 2 that relates to table 1?

this nesting stuff is a riot. i'm tasked to output the results through php, no problem as of now for me. i just wanna be guided with the sql query.

**edit:** output is now fine.
now this:
how do i format this in php? from:

```
1 | item 1 | foo
2 | item 2 | bar
3 | item 3 | bar
```

to

```html
<table border=1px>
<tr><td>1</td><td>item 1</td><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>item 2</td><td rowspan=2>bar</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>item 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

i'm at a loss now on what to do exactly...

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/07/19/671712.aspx

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` (There are plenty of tutorials out there about joining tables)

Comment: ive implemented joins in my query. idk if im wrapping the concept in my head right, but i'm confused on how to display that data in a nested table. not i have results, how do i output this where similar columns are collapsed into one table cell while the rest, where applicable, are not.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt to you table name  .. this   should be the sql code for getting all from the two table

```
select table_1.*, table_2.*
from table_1 
left join table_2 on table_1_id = fk_to_table_1_id;
```